# Use Two Different columns to compare to another worksheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, multiple-columns, vlookup

I have two columns that are different from each other. One containing numbers and the other containing text.
Trying to compare (match) both to another separate worksheet.

Of course, I can VLookup each one separatedly but that doesn't give me the answer I'm looking for.
I want to know if the first two columns correlate with the other worksheet.

I also tried an IF(VLookup but probably did it wrong.

To sum it up. If Column A and Column B are both on the other worksheet, then True or False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a worksheet function that'll do what you want assuming you're only looking in 1 column on worksheet 2. Just replace the values in [] with the actual ranges:

```
=NOT(OR(ISNA(MATCH([ColumnA],[OtherWorksheet],FALSE)), ISNA(MATCH([ColumnB],[OtherWorksheet],FALSE))))
```

Here's an example using actual ranges:

```
=NOT(OR(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,FALSE)), ISNA(MATCH(B1,Sheet2!A:A,FALSE))))
```

FYI: You could also use this formula for conditional formatting if you don't want to display it in a cell.

Just to explain it: 
`MATCH` will return a number if the value is found, otherwise it will be #N/A.
`ISNA` will indicate if the result was #N/A.
`OR` will result in TRUE if either nested `ISNA` indicates TRUE. (Meaning 1 value wasn't found)
`NOT` flips TRUE to FALSE and vice-versa.
End result, if both values are found returns TRUE otherwise displays FALSE.